# Woocommerce - show products in search results before everything else

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Currently I have the following code:

```
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php 
            if ( get_post_type() !== 'post' ) {
                if ( get_post_type() == 'landing-pages' ) {
                    get_template_part( 'templates/content/archive', 'landingpages' );
                } elseif ( get_post_type() == 'product' ) {
                    get_template_part( 'templates/content/archive', 'product' );
                } else {
                    get_template_part( 'templates/content/archive', 'cpt' );
                }
            } else {
                get_template_part( 'templates/content/archive', 'posts' );
            };
        ?>        

    <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php get_template_part( 'templates/modules/nav', 'pagination' ); ?>
```

However, this just displays most recent to oldest. With custom posts, woocommerce products, posts, pages, all mixed togather.

I want only products to be displayed, then once all matching products have been displayed, anything else that matches the search query is returned, eg: other custom post types, pages, and posts.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the following code in functions.php file of your theme.

```
add_filter('posts_orderby','search_sort_custom',10,2);
function search_sort_custom( $orderby, $query )
{
    global $wpdb;

    if(!is_admin() && is_search())
        $orderby =  $wpdb->prefix."posts.post_type DESC, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_date DESC";

    return  $orderby;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, the "testimonials" custom posts get displayed in the search before the products do.  We need products to be displayed first, then everything else. looks like it is on he right track from the quick test I did.

Comment: Actually this doesn't SEEM to be working: testimonials (custom post type) are showing among the products (woocommerce custom post type)